# Chrome Private tabs to regular tab

Tags: google-chrome, private-browsing

I have a plenty of tabs opened in private mode. I would like to open all these tabs in a normal window. Any way to do it without copying each address in the regular tab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### I would like to open all these [private] tabs in a normal window.

Try the [Incognito Tab Switch](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/incognito-tab-switch/ofeampmlffjabmpdebckhpmcjkcjkahi?hl=en):

> The **extension currently supports switching from normal to incognito mode and vice versa** with equivalent functionality. New instances of each window mode are merged as you go; you will only ever have one window in each mode. Multiple tabs can be switched out at once and will still be re-inserted in their correct position among the other tabs.

Source  [Chrome Web Store - Extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions?hl=en)

> When you press the Incognito Tab Switch button, it opens up your
>   current tab in an incognito window. Keep pushing the button, and each
>   tab gets added to the new incognito session. **If you enable the
>   extension to work in incognito mode, you can also switch those tabs
>   back to normal browser tabs with a click.**

Source [Incognito Tab Switch Flips Any Open Tab Over to Incognito Mode](https://lifehacker.com/incognito-tab-switch-flips-any-open-tab-over-to-incogni-512266998)

Comment: The first link leads to a 404. Do you think it's still available @DavidPostill?

Answer (score 3):

Bookmark all tabs (in the incognito window, CTRL-SHIFT-D). Close the window. From the bookmarks menu, right-click on the new folder and choose "Open all in new window".